# How does PIL getdata() organize the pixels?

Tags: python, graphics, python-imaging-library, rgb, pixel

I've used the PIL library to get the RGB values for my image. However, I'm unsure of how the library outputs the final list. Is is a row major operation or is it a column major operation?

Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("simpletest.jpg", "r")
img = img.convert("RGB")

h, w = img.size
pixels = list(img.getdata())
 
print(pixels)
```

I'm unsure of how the list is combined. Does getdata() go row by row over the image and then combine the pixel data together or does it do it column first? And where does it start - top left, bottom left, etc.? I've tried to find this information on the docs but haven't had much luck and would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Pillow documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html?highlight=getdata#PIL.Image.Image.getdata):

> The sequence object is flattened, so that values for line one follow directly after the values of line zero, and so on.

So each element in `pixels` is a tuple containing the red, green, and blue values, respectively. The pixels are ordered left to right, top to bottom, e.i. the first element is the top-left pixel, and the last element is the bottom-right pixel.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you for the clarification!